# android datepicker set max date as 14 years ago

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using this coded to generate date picker in android.

```
DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, y, m, d);
datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Right now `max` date is current date. I want to set it as 14 years ago. How can I do that?

Comment: Use `System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25 * 14)`?

Comment: Now max date is: October, 2014

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the day multiplier. Updated (millis * secs * minutes * daily hours * year days * number of years). It could be a precalculated constant: 441806400000

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by using Calender

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -14);
DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, y, m, d);
datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be by using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new DateTime().minusYears(14));
```